# htaccess rewrite rule is doing something strange

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I go to my site

```
https://testsite.com/ProductsCatalog/Vertical/Boards
```

I get internal server error.

To debug I added a debug flag and it shows this

```
[Sat May 14 15:33:04.430655 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 38242] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:52126] 127.0.0.1 - - [site/sid#7ffae3005dc8][rid#7ffae4879678/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/site/] rewrite 'index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/ProductsCatalog/Vertical/Boards' -> '/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/ProductsCatalog/Vertical/Boards'
[Sat May 14 15:33:04.430663 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 38242] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:52126] 127.0.0.1 - - [site/sid#7ffae3005dc8][rid#7ffae4879678/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/site/] trying to replace context docroot /Library/WebServer/Documents/site with context prefix
[Sat May 14 15:33:04.430669 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 38242] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 127.0.0.1:52126] 127.0.0.1 - - [site/sid#7ffae3005dc8][rid#7ffae4879678/initial/redir#10] [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/site/] internal redirect with /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/ProductsCatalog/Vertical/Boards [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exclude the destination you are rewriting to :

```
 RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

otherwise you will get a rewrite loop error since the pattern `^(.*)$` also matches the uri `index.php`